# How to get the mp3 audio streaming url from a website?

Tags: android, iphone, audio-streaming, live-streaming, internet-radio

I'm trying to build an app for a radio station, but keep running into same error.

This is what it gives me.

http://www.tantalk1340.com/wp-content/plugins/shoutcast-icecast-html5-radio-player/html5/html5icecast.php?id=7&caching=201&rand=2/

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you trying to do this as a one-off, or programmatically?  If a one-off, just watch network requests in your developer tools and look for the actual streaming URL.  (This URL is for a web page.)  If doing it programmatically, you need to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the Link that will generate the HTML page with a player. You can open the link and it has pretty nice javascript code. Below is a snippet that said how to get a stream:

```
                var currentTime = Date.now() || +new Date();

                var stream = {
                    title: "Tan Talk 1340 AM",
                    mp3: "http://home.besedic.com:8000/live?hash="+currentTime 
                },
                ready = false;

                jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function (event) {
                        ready = true;

                        if(autoplayz==false)
                         jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
                        else
                        jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");


                    },
                    pause: function() {
                        jQuery(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
                    },
                    error: function(event) {
                        if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === jQuery.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
                            // Setup the media stream again and play it.
                            jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
                        }
                    },
                    swfPath: "js",
                    supplied: "mp3",
                    preload: "auto",
                    wmode: "window",
                    /*autoPlay: true,*/
                    solution:"flash,html",
                    volume: vol/100,
                    keyEnabled: true
                });
```

If it is not clear from snippet, you URL is:
http ://home.besedic.com:8000/live?hash=+currentTime

[image]